# How to get data from jsp page in struts1

Tags: java, struts-1

I have below JSP page. Using this I can bind data and its working fine.

I am using logic:iterate for binding data from list. 
What I am doing fetch the data from database and set it to list and using this list I can bind data into login iterate.

I am using below VO for bind data:

```
public class EDCPEmployeeRequestForm extends ActionForm {   
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String employeeCode ;
    private String employeeName;
    private String employeeAddress;
    private String cardNo;
    private String employeeEmailId;
    private String employeeContactNo;
    private String company;
    private String strCompany;
    private String employeeWorkCity;
    private String employeeWorkLocation;
    private String band;
    private String status;

    private EDCPNomineeDetailsForm[] nomineeDetailsList;

    // getter and setter method....
    .....
```

Now I want get the data from list which is use in the login:iterator. Why I need if any user login first time then empty list will generate and empty data all the field in which are used within login:iterate.

When user press the submit button in the the above form then below action class is execute :

```
public class EDCPEnrollmentAction extends Action {

    Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @Override
    public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
            HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
        EDCPEmployeeRequestForm eDCPEmployeeRequestForm = (EDCPEmployeeRequestForm) form;

        LOGGER.info("EDCPRequest Object : "+eDCPEmployeeRequestForm.toString());
    }
}
```

Ouput when user press submit button :

> EDCPEmployeeRequestForm [employeeCode=123456, employeeName=Test,
>   employeeAddress=null, cardNo=null, employeeEmailId=test@gmail.com,
>   employeeContactNo=124589652, company=null, strCompany=1001,
>   employeeWorkCity=1001, employeeWorkLocation=10011, band=2D,
>   status=null, nomineeDetailsList=null]

You can see that nomineeDetailsList=null its showing null.

But now problem is that I am getting the value for `nomineeDetailsList` field. Every time I am getting null when I am trying to get value from VO.

My HTML file is designed as below :

```
<html:form action="/eDCPEnrollment" onsubmit="return checkallfields()">
    <logic:iterate id="nomineeData" name="eDCPEmployeeRequestForm" property="nomineeDetailsList" indexId="index" >
    <table width="709" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <td width="162" height=10></td>
            <td width="162"></td>
            <td width="162"></td>
            <td width="163"></td>
            <td width="50"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right" class="text">Name :</td>

            <td align="center"><html:text property="firstName" name="nomineeData"
                    maxlength="25" styleClass="textfield" indexed="true"></html:text></td>
            <td align="center"><html:text property="middleName" name="nomineeData"
                    maxlength="25" styleClass="textfield" indexed="true"></html:text></td>
            <td align="center"><html:text property="lastName" name="nomineeData"
                    maxlength="25" styleClass="textfield" indexed="true"></html:text></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    <tr><td><html:submit styleClass="button"></html:submit></td></tr>
    </table>
</html:form>
```

I am stuck here. Please correct me if I missing something.

Comment: Where you are acessing `nomineeDetailsList` and the value is returning as `null`, did you set any values for `nomineeDetailsList` in form or in action class ?

Comment: set property in jsp page as you can see in the JSP page : property="nomineeDetailsList". I am trying to get the when user press the submit button and then EDCPEnrollmentAction class is called and I am expecting I will get data from this array which is defined in EDCPEmployeeRequestForm  in this bean class and field is nomineeDetailsList. But when I print the bean using to string then I see that nomineeDetailsListis set to null.